# Gulp: issues when concatenating and using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, babeljs

I have a set of Javascript files, which include some vendor files such as jQuery and bootstrap and some ES6 files which need to be 'transpiled' into ES5.

I created a gulp task to process all these files and merge them into one single file:

```
gulp.task("processJs4", () => {
    return gulp.src(tmpJsAssets)
        .pipe(order(tmpJsAssets))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(resources.jsDest))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Javascript task complete...'}))
})
```

where tmpJsAssets is an array of scripts in the order I want them to be processed (first jQuery, second bootstrap and so on). bundle.js is successfully created, but when using it I'm getting the following error coming from one of the transpiled files:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

If I inspect bundle.js I noticed that jQuery is not being 'append' at the beginning of the file. I'm using gulp-order because in other posts I read that it would process the files respecting the order they were passed in.

I also tried using streamqueue but with no luck, I'm getting the same results:

```
gulp.task("processJs4", () => {
    return streamqueue({ objectMode: true }, gulp.src(tmpJsAssets))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(resources.jsDest))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Javascript task complete...'}))
})
```

The only solution I've found was to have to separate tasks that generate two separate files, one for vendors and one for my files. So I thought I could concatenate the files generated for those tasks into one single but it didn't work either.

I gotta use jQuery and bootstrap files, I don't want to install them via npm and then use them.

These are the dependencies used:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-webpack-sourcemaps": "^0.3.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "streamqueue": "^1.1.2",
```

Thanks.

***EDIT: Including tmpJsAssets ***

> [ 'src/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js',
>   'src/js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
>   'src/js/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js',
>   'src/js/items/application.js',   'src/js/items/scroll.js',
>   'src/js/pages/about/about.js',   'src/js/pages/homepage/homepage.js', 
>   'src/js/pages/search-app.js', ]

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the stream from `gulp.src(tmpJsAssets)` directly to `order(orderedTmpJsAssets)`, the specified file paths in `orderedTmpJsAssets` must be **relative** to `tmpJsAssets`.

Suppose you have a project setup like:

```
- src/
  - vendor/
    jQuery.js
    bootstrap.js
    libs.js
  - app/
    ...your JS files
```

You could bundle them in the correct order like:

```
gulp.src('src/**/*.js') // glob all .js files in ./src directory
  .pipe(order([
    'vendor/jQuery.js', // jQuery First
    'vendor/**/*.js',  // other files in the ./src/vendor directory
    'app/**/*.js' // files in the ./src/app directory
  ])
  .pipe(...)
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either. So in gulp.src in passing an array of files since I don't wanna process all files in a specific directory, then, following your advice, in order I'm passing an array of filenames (without the full path since it was already referenced in gulp.src) in the order I want them to be processed. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the value of `tmpJsAssets`? gulp.src should process in order normally, you would only need the order plugin when sorting a glob pattern.